# Dynamically adding elements to android relative layout

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I am having a little problem with Relative Layouts. I'm doing a project in which I have to read some values from a .CSV file and display them dynamically in a Relative Layout. I'll put a couple of code snippets and images and then explain my problem.

First Code snippet:

```
package ekalavya.pratnala.quiz;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.ScrollView;

public class QuizActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Beginning of variable declarations
    File quizSpecs = new File("mnt/sdcard/teacher.csv"); // Read the file
    BufferedReader csvReader = null;
    String line = ""; // Storing each line in a string
    StringTokenizer currentLine = null;
    int noOfQuestions = 0; // Number of questions in the quiz
    int time = 0; // Duration of the quiz
    int[][] quizData; // Storing the quiz specifications in an integer array
    int i = 0, j = 0; // Loop variables
    int[][] questionImages = {
            { R.drawable.a, R.drawable.b, R.drawable.c, R.drawable.d,
                    R.drawable.e, R.drawable.f, R.drawable.g, R.drawable.h,
                    R.drawable.i, R.drawable.j },
            { R.drawable.a_checked, R.drawable.b_checked,
                    R.drawable.c_checked, R.drawable.d_checked,
                    R.drawable.e_checked, R.drawable.f_checked,
                    R.drawable.g_checked, R.drawable.h_checked,
                    R.drawable.i_checked, R.drawable.j_checked },
            { R.drawable.zero, R.drawable.one, R.drawable.two,
                    R.drawable.three, R.drawable.four, R.drawable.five,
                    R.drawable.six, R.drawable.seven, R.drawable.eight,
                    R.drawable.nine },
            { R.drawable.zero_checked, R.drawable.one_checked,
                    R.drawable.two_checked, R.drawable.three_checked,
                    R.drawable.four_checked, R.drawable.five_checked,
                    R.drawable.six_checked, R.drawable.seven_checked,
                    R.drawable.eight_checked, R.drawable.nine_checked } };
    // End of variable declarations

    try {
        csvReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(quizSpecs));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        line = csvReader.readLine();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    currentLine = new StringTokenizer(line, ",");
    noOfQuestions = Integer.parseInt(currentLine.nextToken());
    time = Integer.parseInt(currentLine.nextToken());
    while (currentLine.hasMoreTokens())
        ;
    quizData = new int[noOfQuestions][6];
    for (i = 0; i < noOfQuestions; i++) {
        try {
            line = csvReader.readLine();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        currentLine = new StringTokenizer(line, ",");
        for (j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
            quizData[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(currentLine.nextToken());
        }
    }
    try {
        csvReader.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ScrollView s1 = new ScrollView(this);
    RelativeLayout r1 = new RelativeLayout(this);
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        switch (quizData[i][1]) {
        case 1:
        case 2:
            for (j = 0; j < quizData[i][2]; j++) {
                ImageView option = new ImageView(this);
                option.setImageResource(questionImages[0][j]);
                option.setId(j + (10 * (i + 1)));
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, j - 1
                        + (10 * (i + 1)));
                option.setLayoutParams(params);
                r1.addView(option, params);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    s1.addView(r1, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    this.setContentView(s1);
}
}
```

Image 1: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vzpilyotvgtipbb/pic2.png

Second Code snippet:

```
package ekalavya.pratnala.quiz;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.ScrollView;

public class QuizActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Beginning of variable declarations
    File quizSpecs = new File("mnt/sdcard/teacher.csv"); // Read the file
    BufferedReader csvReader = null;
    String line = ""; // Storing each line in a string
    StringTokenizer currentLine = null;
    int noOfQuestions = 0; // Number of questions in the quiz
    int time = 0; // Duration of the quiz
    int[][] quizData; // Storing the quiz specifications in an integer array
    int i = 0, j = 0; // Loop variables
    int[][] questionImages = {
            { R.drawable.a, R.drawable.b, R.drawable.c, R.drawable.d,
                    R.drawable.e, R.drawable.f, R.drawable.g, R.drawable.h,
                    R.drawable.i, R.drawable.j },
            { R.drawable.a_checked, R.drawable.b_checked,
                    R.drawable.c_checked, R.drawable.d_checked,
                    R.drawable.e_checked, R.drawable.f_checked,
                    R.drawable.g_checked, R.drawable.h_checked,
                    R.drawable.i_checked, R.drawable.j_checked },
            { R.drawable.zero, R.drawable.one, R.drawable.two,
                    R.drawable.three, R.drawable.four, R.drawable.five,
                    R.drawable.six, R.drawable.seven, R.drawable.eight,
                    R.drawable.nine },
            { R.drawable.zero_checked, R.drawable.one_checked,
                    R.drawable.two_checked, R.drawable.three_checked,
                    R.drawable.four_checked, R.drawable.five_checked,
                    R.drawable.six_checked, R.drawable.seven_checked,
                    R.drawable.eight_checked, R.drawable.nine_checked } };
    // End of variable declarations

    try {
        csvReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(quizSpecs));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        line = csvReader.readLine();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    currentLine = new StringTokenizer(line, ",");
    noOfQuestions = Integer.parseInt(currentLine.nextToken());
    time = Integer.parseInt(currentLine.nextToken());
    while (currentLine.hasMoreTokens())
        ;
    quizData = new int[noOfQuestions][6];
    for (i = 0; i < noOfQuestions; i++) {
        try {
            line = csvReader.readLine();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        currentLine = new StringTokenizer(line, ",");
        for (j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
            quizData[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(currentLine.nextToken());
        }
    }
    try {
        csvReader.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ScrollView s1 = new ScrollView(this);
    RelativeLayout r1 = new RelativeLayout(this);
    for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        switch (quizData[i][3]) {
        case 1:
        case 2:
            for (j = 0; j < quizData[i][2]; j++) {
                ImageView option = new ImageView(this);
                option.setImageResource(questionImages[0][j]);
                option.setId(j + (10 * (i + 1)));
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, j - 1
                        + (10 * (i + 1)));
                option.setLayoutParams(params);
                r1.addView(option, params);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    s1.addView(r1, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    this.setContentView(s1);
}
}
```

Image 2: https://www.dropbox.com/s/itazcpshjzbza4t/pic1.png

When the loop in the switch case with variable 'i' is run only once, the second output comes. And if I run it twice, the first output comes. But that's not what I want. I want the first output row to show below the second output row. I know something is wrong in the code but I don't know how to rectify it. Please help me! Also, I want to know how to place those elements anywhere on the screen.

P.S. I haven't been allowed to upload images because my reputation is less than 10 (I'm a newbie here). So, I put them on Dropbox and have put the links here. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Why not use a list with an adapter?

Comment: I'm sorry, but can you please elaborate?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your problem correctly. Don't mind with  what I said.

Comment: Which part can I clarify better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this: I specified only the `RIGHT_OF` property before and hence it didn't know where to place it vertically and so put it at the top. Specifying the `BELOW` property as well fixed the issue.

Comment: I specified only the RIGHT_OF property before and hence it didn't know where to place it vertically and so put it at the top. By specifying the BELOW property as well, I solved it. Can I receive an upvote? Need some rep to include images in future questions.